# Import data from Jira to TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, jira, tfs-2015

I'm planning a move from Jira to Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015 and I can't find a good method of migrating the data between the two systems.

Are there any good methods out there ?

Answer (score 11):

My company recently moved from Jira to TFS. I ended up writing my own utility to do the migration.

I've since published it as open source and it can be found on GitHub here:

https://github.com/KilskyreMan/JiraToTfs.git

The project will compile and run under Visual Studio 2015. It offers various mapping abilities via a GUI that should allow you (if needed) tailor your import.

Hope this helps - Ian.

Answer (score 1):

For now, no documentation mentions how to migrate from Jira to TFS, but there are some plugins to have two-way sync between TFS and Jira, you can take a look at them:

- [TFS4JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.spartez.jira.plugins.bork.tfs4jira) (About About TFS4JIRA, you can get more information at https://confluence.spartez.com/display/TFS4JIRA/About+TFS4JIRA)
- [UseTFS](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.pigsty.jira.plugin.usetfs)
- [Atlassian Connector for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/PLVS)